# Pass DOM Element as a prop in React

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

So I have a component that needs a DOM element passed in as a prop. I'm trying to use it in another component like so:

```
    <div>
        <div className="myPropDiv" ref="myPropDiv">...</div>
        <CustomComponent view={ this.refs.myPropDiv } />
    </div>
```

But that doesn't work because (I suspect) the DOM hasn't been rendered at the point I'm calling `this.refs.myPropDiv`. How would I accomplish something like this?

Comment: Don't do that, you're tightly coupling the sub-component to its parent component. Instead, fire an event or create a callback so the parent component can respond accordingly. You should explain how you planned on using it so we can provide a more thorough solution

Answer (score 3):

In most situations this is not a good idea, and at least it doesn't look like it is following the React way.

Firstly by getting that div via refs, you don't get DOM element but rather backing instance of that div. You can get the DOM element like toomanyredirects is suggesting.

What are you trying to achieve anyway? One advantage of React is you don't have to mess with original DOM, but play with the virtual one. If you want to just display that div inside your component, than pass it like this.

`<CustomComponent>
     <div className="myPropDiv" ref="myPropDiv">...</div>
 </CustomComponent>`

Then, you can access that div inside your CustomComponent as props.children.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly access the DOM, but you can access the DOM element for a React component with `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component)`, so to use it inside a `componentDidMount` call you'd use:

```
var MyComponent = React.createComponent({
  ...
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var component = this,
      node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component);
  }
  ...
});
```

Then if you are looking for a child node of that parent DOM node, you can traverse the DOM normally from that node, for example:

```
var childNode = node.querySelectorAll('.child-node-class')[0];
```

Then you can pass it to wherever you originally wanted it.